# After reinstall magento2 in localhost the dashboard working not properly

Tags: magento-2.1, dashboard

when I am reinstall the magento2 in my localhost the admin not working properly.
sales,products,customers... are not opening properly in my admin panel.[image]

Comment: Have you deploy static content or not?

Comment: i didn't understand clearly

Comment: static content means sir

Comment: Check my below answer, it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy static content by below command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

After run this command check your admin.

Comment: I tried that one but no change

Answer (score 0):

try to run the below Command

**-Static Content Deploy Using Command Line**

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

-Setup Upgrade Using Command Line

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

**-Cache Clean Using Command Line**

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

**-Cache Flush Using Command Line**

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: I tried that one but no change